# Suppose $f(x)$ is such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f(x)dx = \arcsin (t - \sqrt{1/2})$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

Suppose $f(x)$ is such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}  f(x)dx = \arcsin(t - \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})$$ for all $t$ where the right-side expression is defined.

Compute $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx$$

The subscripts on the integrals are both negative infinity - I wasn't sure how to express that with LaTeX. Also it was supposed to be $\sin^{-1}$ but I didn't know how to write the inverse function with a negative exponent. This is a question in a problem book I'm working through.

Thanks.

Comment: In order for $\LaTeX$'s commands to take effect in more than one character, enclose the whole string of characters inbetween { }. For example: e^{tx} will give you $e^{tx}$ while \int _{-\infty}^{+\infty} will give you $\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}$.

Comment: @GitGud Ah ok thanks. I tried parentheses only.

Comment: { } are $\LaTeX$'s parentheses.

Comment: $\arcsin$ is a perfectly reasonable alternative to $\sin^{-1}$ -- arguably, $\arcsin$ is even the *preferable* notation.

Answer (score 6):

Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$, and then set $t$ to zero.

The justification for this is [Leibniz' integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

**Edit**: To clarify: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} e^{tx} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{tx} f(x) dx$$ and so $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x) dx|_{t=0} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx.$$ On the other hand, $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f(x) dx = \frac{d}{dt} \arcsin(t - \sqrt{1/2}) = (-t^2 + t\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2})^{-1/2}$$ and plugging in $t = 0$ in the latter gives you $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Apply the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) . See [Example 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign#Example_3) in section  Examples for evaluating a definite integral in wikipedia page [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: I took the liberty of adding another link to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: But here we integrate on an infinite interval, it requires some more work.

Comment: Remember that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\lim_{u\to -\infty}\int_{u}^{x}+\lim_{v\to +\infty}\int^{v}_{x}$ for all $x$

Comment: Of course, but that's still one more limit sign to exchange with. Remember you differentiate this.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with this.